# Preventing Accidental Clicks on Chrome Picture-in-Picture Window

Tags: windows, windows-10, gaming, mouse-click, window-focus

I'm encountering an issue while gaming where I inadvertently click on the picture-in-picture window, causing disruptions such as moving the window around, pausing the video, or interfering with gameplay controls.

Does anyone know of a solution to prevent accidental clicks on the picture-in-picture window while gaming? Any insights or suggestions would be highly valued. I see that there are quite a few posts asking about this issue, but no answer yet. Perhaps a 3rd party app that can lock application windows from being focused with a hotkey?

I'm on Windows 10 64bit (Brave browser, Chromium-based) if it makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is most unlikely there is a setting to prevent accidental clicks other than mouse settings that already exist.